# django: cleanest way to save every page served

Tags: python, django

I want  to track what all the users of my django site are doing. I want to do this by saving every HTML page served to them. What would be the simplest method to do this? I was currently considering making a decorator that saves the HTML to a file before serving it, but this would require adding that decorator on all of my views, which does not seem ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe a better way would be to save the queries made by the user, because you can always regenerate the html from the query.  Then you could write a middleware to process all incoming requests [As per here](http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter16/) and save to the database the query.  If you really want to save the html, you may use the `process_response` function to do saving afterward.  [Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs#process_response)

Comment: i'd have to not only save the queries but also the POST data, GET data, etc... also, my code and templates might change, which means i wouldn't be able to regenerate the exact same thing the user saw

Comment: I believe the middleware has access to the request object, so the GET and POST data would be accessable.  Why not save the data with the template numbers, so you can combine with a version control system.  According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs#process_response the middleware also has access to the response.

Comment: hmm middleware does indeed seem to be the way to go! thanks, ill look into it

Comment: If you only save the request, the state of the DB itself at the moment the response was generated would need to be saved too. Middleware, however, is an answer. Response middleware would allow you log the response.

Comment: the middleware solution works great! accepting this answer as it's the one that suggested that first. i ended up just saving the generated `.html`

Answer (score 1):

Use django signals.

The `request_finished` signal is called when Django finishes processing an `HttpRequest` which happens at the end of every view where you are serving the page back. Here you can access the `params` set in the response and generate the page the way it would be shown to the user or just save the `response_object` and then run a batch process to visualize it offline.

[Signal documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/)

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a [per site cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs/#the-per-site-cache) and then query the cache to get your stats. However as posted by others middleware would seem ideal.

However - keep in mind that middleware is called on *every request*, so if you are doing i/o heavy tasks like db writes it will negatively affect your site's performance.